# Как в Java можно реализовать Timer чтобы не создавать много объектов?

Tags: java, android, таймер

У меня есть кнопка по нажатии которой запускается класс Timer.

Как сделать чтобы по нажатии на кнопку Если Timer уже существует или работает. То удалить данный Timer и запустить новый, а лучше перезапустить Timer.

Не могу ни как обдумать данную логику....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто посмотреть документацию класса `Timer`, то становится ясно, что нет такого метода, который перезапускает таймер.

> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Есть простое решение, которое просто пересоздает таймер (от того, что объект будет создаваться новый, никаких проблем не будет).
В обработчике клика:

```
if (timer != null) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}
timer = new Timer();
//запуск таймера
```

Comment: Я такое делал получал ошибку. Timer Was Canceled

Comment: Что за ошибка такая? Стек трейс надо прилагать и часть кода, в которой выбросилось исключение.